# Creating functions in a loop R

Tags: r, function, loops

I would like to create an arbitrary number of functions, f_1, f_2, ... ,f_n.

I have no idea how to make a loop like

```
for ( i in 1:n) { 
  f_i = function(x) { exp(x*i) }
end
```

---- edit:

What I actually want to do is to create n functions, multiply all of them, and then integrate the product function n times. After that, create a loop that in every iteration creates a new function (integrating). Let's say,

1. create f(x1,...,xn) = f_1(x1)*...*f_n(x_n) (we can use the exponential above for f_i)
2. then a loop like

   ```
   for (i=1:(n-1)){
     f(x1,...,x(n-i)) <- integrate(f, lower=x(n-i), upper=10)
   }
   ```

This loop should end with a number, but every iteration should give a new function with one variable less than the previous one.

Comment: Welcome to SO!, prima facie, have `f1..fN`,  functions each doing slightly different operations is bad idea. Could you elaborate what are you trying to achieve and why is there a need for N functions

Comment: What about a list of functions? `x <- sapply(1:10, function(i)  function(x) exp(x*i) );
x[[2]](3)`

Comment: thanks for your comments. The previous example was a simplification, but what I actually want to do is to create multivariate functions integrating iteratively. I just edit my post to explain further.

Comment: @jogo if you do that and use R < 3.2.0, please consider lazy evaluation. Once you start calling the functions in `x` they all use `i == 10`. Use `force(i)` inside the anonymous function to prevent this. From R 3.2.0 onwards apply functions do this automatically. However, if you use other means to create a function in a list, please consider the lazy eval problem.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I am using last version of R, Could you please explain a little more your idea?